# Embedding Power BI Preview Dashboards into Webpage

Tags: iframe, web

Our end goal is to be able to display our Power BI Preview dashboards on a signage system.

The signage system has the ability to display webpages that require no authentication.

The plan was to frame the power bi page to a website and have it authenticate to the service and then displaying that page to the signage system.

The problem is that the power bi page is unable to be framed.

Any thoughts/ideas/suggestions on the optimal way of tackling this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**MSDN** has a write up on embedding *Power BI* charts:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbi/archive/2014/12/11/embed-power-view-interactive-reports-in-your-blogs-and-websites.aspx